# How do I improve my code to make it run faster?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.7

I am conducting a project in data science to analyse large volumes of cancer genome data, my computer is relatively inefficient and has a low cpu and low ram. As a result to run through all the samples it take sufficiently too long.

I have tried reducing any excess code, I have tried getting rid of for loops for list comprehensions, I have used multiprocessing to split up my tasks to run faster.

```py
import re
import xlrd
import os
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
import collections
import pandas as pd

if os.path.exists("C:\\Users\\js769\\genomemutations\\Input\\ChromosomesVersion") == True:
    print("chromosomes in folder")
else:
    os.makedirs("C:\\Users\\js769\\genomemutations\\Input\\ChromosomesVersion")
    print(
        "Chromosome Folder Created, Please transfer current version of chromosome number base data to new file."
    )
if os.path.exists("C:\\Users\\js769\\genomemutations\\Input\\MutationSamples") == True:
    print("Add sample data to run.")
else:
    os.makedirs("C:\\Users\\js769\\genomemutations\\Input\\MutationSamples")
    print("Mutation Sample Folder Created, please add mutation sample data to folder.")
if os.path.exists("C:\\Users\\js769\\genomemutations\\output") == True:
    print("3")
else:
    os.makedirs("C:\\Users\\js769\\genomemutations\\output")


# Require editing of this so it works both on a mac or windows system. Currently this version suited to mac because of higher processing power.
# Require ability to check to see if error occurs
def Main(Yeram):
    import os
    import glob
    import errno
    import shutil
    import xlrd
    import pandas as pd
    import time
    import re
    import numpy as np

    FragmentSize = 10000000  # This is fragment size which is adjustable.
    # Code not needed

    Position1 = Yeram.vectx
    Position2 = Yeram.vecty
    samplelist = Yeram.samplelist
    dictA = Yeram.dictA
    FragmentSize = Yeram.FragmentSize
    chromosomesizes = Yeram.chromosomesizes

    def chromosomex_mutation_data(
        chromosomenumber, mutationlist
    ):  # It selects the correct chromosome mutation point data, then it selects the data before the -. Mutation data in form(12-20)
        chromosomexlist = ["0-1"]
        for mutationposition in mutationlist:
            if mutationposition[0:2] == str(chromosomenumber):
                chromosomexlist.append(mutationposition[3:])
            elif mutationposition[0:2] == (str(chromosomenumber) + ":"):
                chromosomexlist.append(mutationposition[2:])

            else:
                continue
        Puremutationdatapoints = [int(mutationposition.split("-")[0]) for mutationposition in chromosomexlist]
        return Puremutationdatapoints

    def Dictionary_Of_Fragment_mutation(FragmentSize, MutationData, ChromosomeNumber):  #
        chromosomes = {}  # Dictionary
        chromosomesize = chromosomesizes[ChromosomeNumber - 1]
        # Opening up specific chromosome data and calculating amount of bases present in chromosome
        Number_of_fragments = int(chromosomesize / FragmentSize)
        for mutation in MutationData:
            for i in range(0, (Number_of_fragments), 1):
                a = (
                    "Chromosome"
                    + str(ChromosomeNumber)
                    + "Fragment"
                    + str(i)
                    + ",Basepairs "
                    + str(i * FragmentSize + 1)
                    + "-"
                    + str(i * FragmentSize + FragmentSize)
                )
                if mutation in range(i * FragmentSize + 1, i * FragmentSize + FragmentSize + 1):
                    if chromosomes.get(a) == None:
                        chromosomes.update({a: 1})
                    else:
                        b = (chromosomes.get(a)) + 1
                        chromosomes.update({a: b})
                else:
                    if chromosomes.get(a) == None:
                        chromosomes.update({a: 0})
                    else:
                        continue

        return chromosomes  # adds

    # This adds mutations or no mutation to each fragment for chromosome,makes dicitonaries

    def DictionaryRead(FragmentSize, Dict, ChromosomeNumber):
        chromosomesize = chromosomesizes[ChromosomeNumber - 1]
        Number_of_fragments = int(chromosomesize / FragmentSize)
        chromosomefragmentlist = []
        for i in range(0, (Number_of_fragments), 1):
            a = (
                "Chromosome"
                + str(ChromosomeNumber)
                + "Fragment"
                + str(i)
                + ",Basepairs "
                + str(i * FragmentSize + 1)
                + "-"
                + str(i * FragmentSize + FragmentSize)
            )
            chromosomefragmentlist.append(str(Dict.get((a))))
        return chromosomefragmentlist

    # This uses dictionary to create list

    def forwardpackage2(FragmentSize, PureMutationData):
        C = []  # list of data in numerical order 0 = no mutation
        for i in range(1, 23, 1):
            A = chromosomex_mutation_data(i, PureMutationData)  # Purifies Data
            B = Dictionary_Of_Fragment_mutation(FragmentSize, A, i)  # Constructs Dictionary
            C += DictionaryRead(
                FragmentSize, B, i
            )  # Uses constructed Dictionary amd generates list of numbers, each number being a fragment in numerical order.
        return C

    def Mutationpointdata(Position1, Position2, dictA, FragmentSize):  # Require dictA
        vectx = Position1
        vecty = Position2
        Samplesandmutationpoints = []
        for i in range(vectx, vecty):
            print(samplelist[i])
            new = [k for k, v in dictA.items() if int(v) == samplelist[i]]
            mutationlist = [excelsheet.cell_value(i, 23) for i in new]
            mutationlist.sort()
            Samplesandmutationpoints.append(forwardpackage2(FragmentSize, mutationlist))
        return Samplesandmutationpoints

    # Opening sample data from excel table

    return Mutationpointdata(Position1, Position2, dictA, FragmentSize)  # yeram to james samples


def ChromosomeSequenceData(ChromosomeNumber):  # Formats the chromosome file into readable information
    with open(
        r"C:\Users\js769\genomemutations\Input\ChromosomesVersion\chr" + str(ChromosomeNumber) + ".fa"
    ) as text_file:
        text_data = text_file.read()
        listA = re.sub("\n", "", text_data)
        # list2=[z for z in text_data if z!= "\n"]
        if ChromosomeNumber < 10:
            ChromosomeSequenceData = listA[5:]
        else:
            ChromosomeSequenceData = listA[6:]
    return ChromosomeSequenceData


def basepercentage_single(
    i, FragmentSize, ChromosomeSequenceData
):  # Creates a list of base percentage known for certain type of chromosome.
    sentence = ChromosomeSequenceData[(i * FragmentSize + 1) : (i * FragmentSize + FragmentSize)]
    a = sentence.count("N") + sentence.count("n")
    c = str(((FragmentSize - a) / FragmentSize) * 100) + "%"
    return c


def basepercentage_multiple(
    FragmentSize, ChromosomeSequenceData
):  # Creates a a list of base percentages known which correspond with the dna fragments for every chromosome.
    fragmentamount = int(len(ChromosomeSequenceData) / FragmentSize)
    list = [
        basepercentage_single(i, FragmentSize, ChromosomeSequenceData) for i in range(0, (fragmentamount), 1)
    ]
    return list


def FragmentEncodedPercentage(
    FragmentSize
):  # Packages a list of base percentages known which correspond with the dna fragments for every chromosome.
    Initial_list = [basepercentage_multiple(FragmentSize, ChromosomeSequenceData(i)) for i in range(1, 23, 1)]
    List_of_fragment_encoded_percentages = [item for sublist in Initial_list for item in sublist]
    return List_of_fragment_encoded_percentages


def chromosomefragmentlist(
    FragmentSize, ChromosomeNumber
):  # Creares a list of fragment sizes for a specific chromosome.
    chromosomesize = chromosomesizes[ChromosomeNumber - 1]
    Number_of_fragments = int(chromosomesize / FragmentSize)
    chromosomefragmentlist = []
    for i in range(0, (Number_of_fragments), 1):
        a = (
            "Chromosome"
            + str(ChromosomeNumber)
            + "Fragment"
            + str(i)
            + ",Basepairs "
            + str(i * FragmentSize + 1)
            + "-"
            + str(i * FragmentSize + FragmentSize)
        )
        chromosomefragmentlist.append(str(((a))))
    return chromosomefragmentlist


def GenomeFragmentGenerator(
    FragmentSize
):  # Creates the genome fragments for all chromosomes and adds them all to a list.
    list = [chromosomefragmentlist(FragmentSize, i) for i in range(1, 23, 1)]
    A = [item for sublist in list for item in sublist]
    return A


def excelcreation(
    mutationdata, samplelist, alpha, bravo, FragmentSize, A, B
):  # Program runs sample alpha to bravo and then constructs excel table
    data = {"GenomeFragments": A, "Encoded Base Percentage": B}
    for i in range(alpha, bravo):
        data.update({str(samplelist[i]): mutationdata[i]})
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=A)
    export_csv = df.to_csv(
        r"C:/Users/js769/genomemutations/output/chromosomeAll.csv", index=None, header=True
    )


start_time = time.time()

# Code determine base fragment size
FragmentSize = 1000000


chromosomesizes = []  # This calculates the base pair sizes for each chromosome.
for i in range(1, 23):
    with open(r"C:\Users\js769\genomemutations\Input\ChromosomesVersion\chr" + str(i) + ".fa") as text_file:
        text_data = text_file.read()
        list = re.sub("\n", "", text_data)
        if i < 10:
            chromosomesizes.append(len(list[5:]))
        else:
            chromosomesizes.append(len(list[6:]))


wb = xlrd.open_workbook("C:/Users/js769/genomemutations/input/MutationSamples/Complete Sample For lungs.xlsx")
excelsheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
excelsheet.cell_value(0, 0)
sampleswithduplicates = [excelsheet.cell_value(i, 5) for i in range(1, excelsheet.nrows)]
samplelist = []
for sample in sampleswithduplicates:
    if sample not in samplelist:
        samplelist.append(int(sample))  # Constructs list of sample , each sample only comes up once


dictA = {}
counter = 1  # Creates a dictionary where it counts the
for sample in sampleswithduplicates:
    dictA.update({counter: int(sample)})
    counter = counter + 1


A = GenomeFragmentGenerator(FragmentSize)
B = FragmentEncodedPercentage(FragmentSize)


value = collections.namedtuple(
    "value", ["vectx", "vecty", "samplelist", "dictA", "FragmentSize", "chromosomesizes"]
)
SampleValues = (
    value(
        vectx=0,
        vecty=2,
        samplelist=samplelist,
        dictA=dictA,
        FragmentSize=FragmentSize,
        chromosomesizes=chromosomesizes,
    ),
    value(
        vectx=2,
        vecty=4,
        samplelist=samplelist,
        dictA=dictA,
        FragmentSize=FragmentSize,
        chromosomesizes=chromosomesizes,
    ),
    value(
        vectx=4,
        vecty=6,
        samplelist=samplelist,
        dictA=dictA,
        FragmentSize=FragmentSize,
        chromosomesizes=chromosomesizes,
    ),
    value(
        vectx=6,
        vecty=8,
        samplelist=samplelist,
        dictA=dictA,
        FragmentSize=FragmentSize,
        chromosomesizes=chromosomesizes,
    ),
    value(
        vectx=8,
        vecty=10,
        samplelist=samplelist,
        dictA=dictA,
        FragmentSize=FragmentSize,
        chromosomesizes=chromosomesizes,
    ),
    value(
        vectx=10,
        vecty=12,
        samplelist=samplelist,
        dictA=dictA,
        FragmentSize=FragmentSize,
        chromosomesizes=chromosomesizes,
    ),
    value(
        vectx=12,
        vecty=14,
        samplelist=samplelist,
        dictA=dictA,
        FragmentSize=FragmentSize,
        chromosomesizes=chromosomesizes,
    ),
    value(
        vectx=14,
        vecty=16,
        samplelist=samplelist,
        dictA=dictA,
        FragmentSize=FragmentSize,
        chromosomesizes=chromosomesizes,
    ),
)


print("starting multiprocessing")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool(4) as p:
        result = p.map(Main, SampleValues)

    Allmutationdata = []
    for i in result:
        for b in i:
            Allmutationdata.append(b)

    excelcreation(Allmutationdata, samplelist, 0, 16, FragmentSize, A, B)

print("My program took " + str(time.time() - start_time) + " to run")
```

So the program runs that isn't the issue, the issue is the time it runs,can anyone spot anywhere where my code maybe at fault.

Comment: If you wish to use the code , download the current version of human chromosome base data. And then go on cosmic and download a cancer genome sample to run, you must name cancer genome file as Complete Sample For Lungs

Comment: [codereview.se]

Comment: Have you profiled your code with one of the Python profilers to see where it spends the most time?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better suited to [codereview.se]

Comment: You  should e´definitely take a look to the `format()` function of strings instead of repetitive string concatenations. Otherwise I see no reason, that you have a brute force algorithm involving combinatorics and therefore huge loop iterations.

Comment: Did you analyze whether you are running low on RAM, or if your CPU is performing at 100% load?

Comment: @Epion I am using 100% CPU usage at the point of multiprocessing.

Comment: @AKX I have done in the past and the main crux of the time consumption is within function forwardpackage2, which I have tried to optimise.

Comment: @guidot Thank you for the suggestion, I will take a look now.

Comment: #Sayse Do you believe this is the best place to get answers for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This article [How to make your pandas loop run 72,000x faster](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-your-pandas-loop-71-803-times-faster-805030df4f06) has really resonated with me and I think will help you.

It provides clear instructions on how to `vectorize` your for loops to drastically speed them up

Methods to speed up a `For Loop`:

1. Utilize pandas [`iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)
   ~321 times faster

   Example

```py
for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
     print(index, row)
```

2. Pandas Vectorization
   ~9280 times faster

   Example

```py
df.loc[((col1 == val1) & (col2 == val2)), column_name] = conditional_result
```

3. Numpy Vectorization
   ~72,000 times faster

   Example

```py
df.loc[((col1.values == val1) & (col2.values == val2)), column_name] = conditional_result
```

By adding `.values` we receive a numpy array.

---

Credit for the timing results [goes to this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-your-pandas-loop-71-803-times-faster-805030df4f06)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24230678)

Comment: Good point - Thank you for the review @Rob I will update the answer to include more detail

Comment: @AnthonyR Could you give an example of it being implemented in my code please.